# General cell in excel to ms access date

Tags: ms-access

I have this column in excel in general cell format that contains the date in the following format. eg "18-05-2013" which is "DD-MM-YYYY".

In access, it somehow comes out automatically in this format "##/@@/****".
Where ## and @@ they sometime treat it as day, sometimes treat it as the month.

Somehow it is messed up. What is the way to format given my situation?

The format I want it to be is "DD/MM/YYYY" in access

Comment: you can add a format in the table where you declare the date. if you go to the line of the date than you should see a field to specify "Format", there you can define how the date comes out

Answer (score 0):

A quick use of the replace function solved it!

Hiring Date: Replace([Hire Date],"-","/")